# Stack Overflow: шутки здесь неуместны

Tags: поддержка, faq

Мы заметили, что один из вопросов на Stack Overflow, а именно — [Strangest language feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature) был несколько раз закрыт и открыт повторно. Сам вопрос был немногословен:

> Каковы, по вашему мнению, самые странные, неожиданные, шокирующие особенности языков программирования, с которыми вы когда-либо сталкивались?

Согласен, этот вопрос нельзя назвать идеальным для нашего сообщества, ведь, [согласно справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help):

> **Не стоит задавать субъективные, спорные вопросы, а также те, которые могут вызвать бурю обсуждений.** Наше сообщество — не дискуссионный форум, Stack Overflow – это место для вопросов, которые имеют ответы!

Мы думаем, некоторые участники сообщества уже поняли, что Stack Overflow — *весьма серьезное сообщество*, и если ваш вопрос в точности не соответствует нашим требованиям, он абсолютно недопустим. **Иными словами, мы, на Stack Overflow, ненавидим юмор.**

Впрочем, это не совсем так.

Если мне не изменяет память, существуют три общих правила, определяющие релевантность вопроса тематике сообщества:

1. Соответствует ли вопрос критериям, сформулированным в [справке Stack Overflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help)?
2. Принят ли вопрос участниками сообщества, о чем свидетельствуют положительный рейтинг, добавление в «избранное», большое количество просмотров и наличие ответов?
3. Могу ли я узнать что–то новое из вопроса, чтобы еще лучше делать свою работу?

Что мы имеем в случае нашего «юморного» вопроса [Strangest language feature («Странности языков программирования»)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature)?

> 1. Соответствует ли вопрос критериям, сформулированным в [справке Stack Overflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help)?

Нет, не совсем.

> 2. Принят ли вопрос участниками сообщества, о чем свидетельствуют положительный рейтинг, добавление в «избранное», большое количество просмотров и наличие ответов?

Да. Вопрос имеет высокий рейтинг, массу просмотров, добавлений в «Избранное», множество развернутых ответов.

> 3. Могу ли я узнать что–то новое из вопроса, чтобы еще лучше делать свою работу?

Да. Спорные моменты синтаксиса некоторых языков программирования — извечная боль программистов, и чем большее число разработчиков узнают об этих нюансах, тем лучше будет для всех.

Как пел рокер Мит Лоуф, [«два из трех — уже неплохо»](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=two+out+of+three+ain%27t+bad). К слову, именно правило №3 является определяющим в большинстве спорных ситуаций.

**Мы не хотим, чтобы на сайте задавались «юмористические» вопросы**. Мы ни в коем случае не собираемся жертвовать нашей миссией — предоставлением сервиса вопросов и ответов, превращаясь в веселый, но бездумный форум наподобие Reddit или Digg. Однако мы стремимся к определенному балансу: мир без юмора — все равно, что мир без пони и сладкой ваты; покажите того монстра, который захотел бы жить *в таком мире*!

Все мы программисты, и всем нам хотелось бы верить в то, что мироздание совершенно и бинарно, и «юмористические» вопросы должны быть или строго запрещены, или безусловно разрешены. Мы не хотим лишать вас иллюзий, но в мире, если можно так выразиться, есть место и для плавающей запятой. *Иногда* мы будем разрешать задавать несерьезные вопросы, соответствующие упомянутым ранее трем правилам, но **в очень ограниченном количестве**.

На Stack Overflow, вопреки общепринятому мнению, мы отнюдь не против юмора. Но допускать его мы планируем дозированно, не теряя серьезного выражения лица. :)

---

Свободный перевод публикации [@Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) «[Stack Overflow: Where We Hate Fun](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)» от  4.01.2010.

Comment: IMHO стоит добавить, что первоисточник аж 10-го года...

Comment: точные науки вообще идут без шуток. но человек не машина, надо иногда вносить мимолетный юмор...