# Банан на 299 дней?

Tags: обсуждение, чат

Ого, бан на 299 дней дали. 
Я хз за что, дал лишь ссылку на гитхаб в чате немного рекламного характера.

Мб разбаним? 299 дней многовато.

Ссылка на транскрипт: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34689977#34689977

[image: Снимок экрана чата]

Comment: Ну вам в ЛС наверняка написали причину.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, в том то и дело что не написали.

Comment: Бан распространяется только на чат. Мог быть установлен автоматически за большое количество флагнутых сообщений.

Comment: @Grundy, на 300 дней? Серьезно?

Comment: @monobogdan, вполне, бан _накопительный_, каждый следующий больше предыдущего. Есть пользователь, который был забанен в чатах на 416 дней

Comment: @Grundy, так я был забанен в прошлый раз на 30 минут.

Comment: Текст очень плохо видно на картинке. Трудно понять, есть ли там действительно сообщение о бане...

Comment: @ALEXOLUT, но ведь самого сообщения нет, за что меня забанили то? Я могу тоже написать бота который будет флаговать каждое сообщение с 100 акков, и того человека, под руку которому попался бот, забанят просто так?

Comment: @monobogdan такой наивный и смешной.

Answer (score 8):

До этой длительной блокировки вы уже получали две за 15 тревог оставленных на ваши сообщения. Более того, вам несколько раз однозначно указали на то, что у нас не принято оскорблять. После истечения времени блокировки, вы продолжили намеренно публиковать вредительские сообщения.

Подобное поведение классифицируется как вредоносный шум, отвлекающий людей от полезной работы. (Что еще не мало важно, вы вредите себе и вашей репутации как профессионала. Если не остановиться в какой–то момент, то можно потерять интерес к профессии.)

Хотите учиться - пожалуйста! Уверен, сообщество не будет держать на вас зла и ответит на все ваши вопросы *по программированию* на [основном сайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/).

Пожалуйста, помните, Stack Overflow – профессиональное сообщество, созданное для разрешения рабочих задач, [шутки здесь не уместны](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2697/).

Comment: Так до сведения на аккаунте monobogdan1 я оскорблял в чате, это уже "не считается"
А кто флаговал, я хз, как употребленное мной слово может быть оскорблением, когда это просто более грубое выражение "иностранца", но отнюдь не мат и не оскорбление ;)

Comment: @monobogdan Помните, [оскорбить можно и вполне обычным словом](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4020/6).

Comment: хорошо, разбан возможен?

Comment: @monobogdan Конечно! Блокировка автоматически снимется по истечению времени.

Comment: а смысл мне ждать почти год за маты на другом аккаунте? А есть док-ва что на том аккаунте писал в чат именно я?

Давайте ещё в CS: GO введём такие блокировки, и точно будет все классно.

Comment: @monobogdan простите конечно, но что за *лепет*: *доказательства что в чат писал я*. предупреждения были ***учетной записи*** бан получила учетная запись

Comment: Так стоп, подождите, за оскорбления я получил бан ДО ЭТОГО на 30 минут. А потом во время дисскусии мне прилетел еще один на 300дней. Это как понимать?

Comment: @monobogdan Вы получили блокировку сначала на 30 минут от системы, затем на 60 минут от модератора другого сообщества, далее, за повторное _намеренное_ оскорбление, вы получили блокировку на год, и, судя по вашим комментариям, которые пришлось модерировать, не зря.

Comment: Давайте просто дадим мне шанс и разбаним

Comment: @monobogdan, чем Вы отличаетесь от остальных забаненных участников, что вам нужно давать шанс?

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму очевидно же, чтобы не наслать гнев  ̶б̶о̶ж̶и̶й̶  ботов, которые будут в свои 100 виртуальных рожиц флагать сообщения в чате