# Допустимы ли вопросы, где подразумевается работа за автора?

Tags: поддержка

Что делать с вопросами, ответы на которые подразумевают написание кода или предоставление иного решения, когда автор не приводит в теле вопроса своей реализации?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Работа за автора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/231/23044)

Comment: Кстати никак не пойму, почему тогда закрыли [мой вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/544622/130)

Answer (score 28):

> ### Кратко
>
> Допустимы и приветствуются.
>   <sub>(Вопросы, в которых подразумевается работа за автора != вопросы–домашние задания.)</sub>

### Прежде всего то, что делать не стоит, как в ответах, так и в комментариях.

1. *Навешивать ярлыки на вопрос или на его автора.* Часто случается, что из текста вопроса, который написал автор, страстно желающий получить ответ, не до конца понятна сама техническая проблема. Крайне редко, некоторым удачливым участникам все же удается догадаться, в чем суть проблемы и ответить на вопрос, основываясь на личном профессиональном опыте, все же, угадать «конечно же, очевидные всем» мотивы, побудившие человека опубликовать вопрос в том виде, в котором он был опубликован, и состояние его окружения, в момент написания вопроса – *невозможно*, каким бы опытом вы ни обладали.
2. *Подшучивать над вопросом или его автором*. Stack Overflow – это инструмент профессионального разработчика: [шутки здесь неуместны](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2697/). Размещая *для вас* безобидный комментарий, показывающий «насколько автор вопроса поспешен в своих выводах», вы можете обидеть коллегу: никто не хочет чувствовать себя глупым, ни новичок, ни профессионал.
3. *«Учить жизни»*. Stack Overflow о программировании. «Учить людей жизни» не входит в миссию проекта и является вредоносным шумом.

### Я даю только конструктивную критику!

Сложно оспорить факт, что конструктивная критика полезна. Но, пожалуйста, помните - все хорошо в меру: если в вопросе присутствует огромное количество комментариев с критикой, но нет ни одного толкового ответа, такая критика не будет услышана.

Представьте ситуацию, в которой старшеклассника просят решить задачу по высшей математике из университета, когда он, не зная ничего о общепринятых подходах в ВУЗах, приводит свои доводы, но в ответ получает не подсказку, а критику, много критики, и не только подходов к решению задачи, а терминологии, грамотности и структуры самих высказываний и даже отсутствия интонации в речи…

Ситуацию можно изменить, если подходить систематически, шаг за шагом обучая новых участников правилам и нормам сообщества. Обучение требует времени, оно не происходит мгновенно. *Если вы видите несколько «критикующих» комментариев под вопросом, пожалуйста, не добивайте автора еще одним, опубликуйте развернутый ответ!* Ваши знания, желание помочь и личный пример являются лучшим стимулом не только к изучению правил сообщества, но и к изучению дисциплины в общем.

### Допустимы ли вопросы без предоставления текущей реализации?

Чтобы ответить на этот вопрос, стоит обратиться к миссии проекта и то, как подобные вопросы на нее влияют. Миссия Stack Overflow, относительно базы знаний, в краткой форме, звучит следующим образом: ***«собрать базу многократно используемых решений прикладных задач».*** Взяв во внимание, что:

- чем больше различных задач в нашей базе знаний, тем больше наш вклад в развитие русскоязычного сообщества разработчиков;
- без вопросов, нет ответов – сначала публикуется вопрос, затем ответы, вопрос – это ключ к будущем знаниям, полезным сообществу.

Можно смело говорить – да, допустимы и приветствуются.

Типичный примером может служить вопрос на Stack Overflow на английском: [How do I redirect to another page in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/). Казалось бы, «что может проще»? Обратите внимание, что вопрос получил более трех с половиной миллионов просмотров и 64 ответа, 63 из которых имеют положительный рейтинг!

Публикация вопроса, который еще никто не задавал – это помощь в развитии сайта!

### Как поступать с подобными вопросами, если они не вписываются в нашу модель?

1. *Главное – знания сообщества*. В общем случае, не важно, является ли вопрос чьим–то заданием и сколько времени автор вопроса потратил на составление примера кода. Важно – будет ли данный вопрос полезен сообществу в будущем. Если да, его стоит оставить, если нет – проголосовать против и за закрытие. Пожалуйста, помните, отвечая на вопрос, основную ценность вы создаете не для автора вопроса, а для сотен (а иногда сотен тысяч) коллег, которые попадут на сайт из поиска. При этом, эти коллеги (а) сэкономят уйму времени на поиск решения, воспользовавшись вашим объяснением, (б) не зададут такой–же вопрос повторно.
2. *Внесите правку, при необходимости*. Если вопрос в исходном виде не соответствует формату или правилам Stack Overflow, и вы считаете, что можете опубликовать полезный сообществу ответ, пожалуйста, внесите необходимую для этого правку в вопрос. Оптимально, если вопрос с ответом после правки примут энциклопедический вид: вопрос – четкое описание нишевой проблемы, ответ – развернутое описание ее решения.
3. *[Поисковики ссылаются на Stack Overflow, но ни в коем случае не наоборот](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2166/6)*.
4. *Любой профессиональный опыт по тематике сайта – бесценен*. Вопрос либо есть в базе знаний Stack Overflow на русском и новый должен быть закрыт как дубликат, либо его нет и он полезен.

### В Рунете принято шутить над новичками, ведь так мы их «учим жизни»?

Stack Overflow на русском – всегда был, есть и останется островом знаний, где нет места вредоносному шуму: всему, что не касается тематики конкретного вопроса. Атмосфера знаний в сообществе подразумевает исключительно профессиональное общение, без которого невозможно добиться взаимного уважения участников друг к другу, а как результат, создать само сообщество.

С самого первого дня существования Stack Overflow на русском мы считали, что «профессиональный Рунет» устал от сарказма, взаимных оскорблений и неуместных шуток. Наш девиз:

> Меньше слов, больше дела: есть что сказать по теме вопроса – напиши развёрнутый ответ.

В нашем сообществе нет «традиций» проявлять неуважение в любой форме вне зависимости от возраста, пола, размера багажа знаний, профессионального опыта или правоты в конкретном вопросе.

Победить болезнь неконструктивного профессионального общения в Рунете – уникальная возможность данная именно нашему русскоязычному сообществу. Более того, по большому счету, мы активно с ней справляемся в рамках нашего сайта, являясь примером для остальных.

Чем больше база знаний Stack Overflow на русском, тем меньше шансов нашим коллегам попасть из поиска на весь тот информационный мусор, окружающий нас еще несколько лет назад, а значит и перенять старые, надоевшие всем шаблоны общения с оскорблениями.

Comment: Плюсую двумя руками -) Хотел бы особо обратить внимание, что в своей оценке -- `"Важно – будет ли данный вопрос полезен сообществу в будущем. Если да, его стоит оставить, если нет – проголосовать против и за закрытие."` всем стоит быть поосмотрительней (минусовать, может, и без оглядки, а закрывать, пожалуй, только очевидный бред)

Comment: Можно краткую выжимку перед основной частью? Что-то вроде `tl;dr`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Несмотря на его длину, нет ничего, с чем бы не согласился. Ещё на практике бы его придерживались...

Comment: выделил миссию, так как она определяет какие действия полезны на сайте
и помогает понять мотивацию откуда правила берутся¶

Возможно, стоит явно упомянуть, что только полезные (решающие
прикладную проблему, встречающуюся у многих людей) вопросы, которые
могут быть восприняты как "работа за автора" допустимы. К примеру,
если вопрос явно содержит перечисление "как сделать A, B, C" и его
нельзя переформулировать в виде "как сделать X" (где X это *одна*
практическая задача), то стоит предложить автору задать отдельные
вопросы: "Как сделать A", "Как сделать B", "Как сделать C", а вопрос...

Comment: ..."как сделать A, B, C" закрыть как "слишком общий" (подкатегория:
вопрос-список), то есть вопрос-картинка задания из учебника из
нескольких несвязных пунктов следует удалить¶ Можно ещё явно адресовать пару пунктов от критиков предлагаемой
политики: 1- "если вопрос описывает проблему, встречающуюся у многих
людей, то его и так зададут" (то есть в чём смысл защищать плохие по
форме вопросы, если его в лучшей форме зададут позже, если
проблема действительно у многих людей возникает) -- можно ответить,
что правка вопроса до хорошей формы именно сейчас может помочь росту
сайта...

Comment: ... (сетевые эффекты)¶ 2- «"эксперты" покинут сайт из-за засилья тривиальных вопросов» (дело
не в том, что вопрос простой (программисты постоянно учат новые вещи),
а в отсутствии минимальной культуры по отладке у людей, которые только
начинают, что отражается на форме вопроса -- это открытый вопрос: (с
одной стороны про SO ещё до официального запуска говорили, что ["real
expert"](https://goo.gl/6CSlak)
на вопросы отвечать не будут и [homework вопросы чуть ли не с беты
обсуждаются](https://goo.gl/V8oWuM)),
эксперименты на SO с различными вариациями причин-закрытия,
заканчиваются тем,

Comment: ...что полезные вопросы попадают под раздачу, а
приливный поток некачественных вопросов это не
останавливает. Абсолютные новички преобладают. Нельзя ожидать, что большинство будет help читать, хотя конечно, ненавязчиво, подсказки при создании вопроса стоит предлагать¶ Ещё может стоит обратное рассмотреть: помимо очередей для вопросов с
проблемами, создать очередь для вопросов, которые были бы "интересны"
даже опытному разработчику (вопрос не обязан быть чересчур сложным,
[к примеру](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/4279)). Это уже
отчасти присутствует в форме объявления конкурса...

Comment: ...  для вопроса для привлечения внимания (правда, я не могу найти вкладку featured в новом интерфейсе на SO). К примеру, посмотреть на список вопросов заплюсованных 10k+ пользователями и если это значимый сигнал, то опубликовать их в видном месте¶ Хорошая рекомендация: [*качество* вопроса можно голосованием отметить
плюс/минус.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/257979/4279) И только,
[если вопрос не вписывается в *тематику* сайта, то его следует
закрыть](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152067/137096).  (что [к
удалению может вести](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296609/4279))

Comment: `... и приветствуются.` кем?

Comment: @jfs Спасибо за комментарии! Как мне кажется, данный ответ может слишком большим, если включить в него все рекомендации. Было бы здорово, если бы вы опубликовали вопрос, к примеру «Рекомендации по работе с вопросами, где подразумевается работа за автора».

Comment: @alexolut Идеологией проекта и теми, кто её разделяет.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky судя по тому, как закрываются подобные вопросы, сложно сказать, что сообщество разделяет эту точку зрения.

Comment: Может таки "Допустимы, но не приветствуются"? А то у меня тут шесть вариантов контрольных по информатике... Начинать заливать?

Comment: @vp_arth Все зависит от ваших вопросов. Если они имеют _прикладное значение_ для сообщества в контексте базы знаний, пожалуйста, публикуйте!

Comment: @vp_arth вы же знаете что ответы будут в стиле гольфа (в лучшем случае) в худшем - зададут 10 уточняющих вопросов, доколупаются до формулировок и закроют как непонятный)

Comment: @alexolut Как мне кажется, сообщество здесь разделилось во мнении. Учитывая факт, что закрывать проще, чем отвечать, мы видим больше закрытых подобных вопросов, чем с ответом.

Comment: @alexolut Крайне важно учесть, что в исходной форме вопрос может не соответствовать формату сайта и необходимо внести правку, причем, иногда, незначительную. Допустимо, если после правки вопрос потеряет немного исходной конкретики (например, будет рассмотрен общий случай, а не частный).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky мне кажется надо переформулировать `приветствуются` во что-то иное. Например, `но есть нюансы...` и тут уже следует читать пост целиком.

Comment: Хорошо, давайте проведём [эксперимент,](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/636790/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8) насколько приветливо сообщество к таким вопросам.

Comment: @vp_arth (1) В этом вопросе нет вопроса. (2) вы рассматриваете частный случай, а не общий: сформулируйте, пожалуйста, проблему в общем случае.

Comment: @vp_arth надо было нового юзера завести

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ну сделайте правку дописав "как это сделать оптимально?"

Comment: @pavel Если сформулировать вопрос в общем случае, можно увидеть, что он лежит за пределами того, что мы подразумеваем под «программированием». То есть приведенный вопрос не может быть использован как пример, так как не является тематичным для сайта.

Comment: Общий случай - это - "как решать задачи по программированию?" Или чуть менее общий?

Comment: @vp_arth вы сами решение знаете?) я то знаю, но писать не буду. Кстати экспиремент закончился, вопрос закрыт, можно расходится.

Comment: Ну да, простая же задачка. Приведенная операция увеличивает дробь. Выполняем операцию, пока меньше, дальше смотрим, если больше выводим 0, если равно выводим количество операций.

Comment: @vp_arth не вижу вопроса, но если он ясно сформулирован (не нужно гадать, [все части головоломки на месте](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3976/23044)), имеет разумный охват (существует краткий ответ), по теме сайта (та же прикладная проблема может и у других людей возникнуть) и не является точным дубликатом уже существующего вопроса, то не важно что кому-то он был дан как задание по информатике—автор один, а возможных посетителей этого вопроса из веб-поисковика может быть гораздо больше.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky комментарий я оставил, чтобы пару (разумных на мой взгляд) доводов против явно адресовать—лучше конечно это в  вашем ответе сделать, но не страшно, если в комментарии останется. Остальное это просто идеи, которые по ходу возникли. Мне данные голосования не доступны—не могу посмотреть являются ли голоса 10k пользователей полезным сигналом того что является ли вопрос "интересным"...

Comment: ... Или хотя бы есть ли программный критерий, чтобы поместить вопрос в очередь кандидатов на "интересный" вопрос, где люди могут голосовать, редактировать, skip вопрос и скажем после 5 голосов «за» помещать в официальную [интересный] категорию.

Comment: @vp_arth: ещё данные в подтверждение мысли *"автор один, а возможных посетителей этого вопроса из веб-поисковика может быть гораздо больше."*: [*"Almost 95% of our non-automated traffic is to question views"*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/03/09/anyone-actually-visit-stack-overflows-home-page/). Это не гипотетические примеры, что злобный тролль может на сайте сотворить, а то как себя реальные пользователи ведут.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, при всем моем уважении, не могу согласиться. Жесткость модерации, принципиальность, требовательность и сознательные ограничения сделали SO таким, какой он был. Теперь же я вынужден менять вопрос кардинально, чтобы он приобрел вид типичного для сообщества. Пример, почти вся ветка пилится вручную http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script Так и подмывает спросить некоторых авторов: "Если описан плохо тег - скажите, я переделаю, но зачем игнорировать его содержимое?"

Comment: @oshliaer Пожалуйста, раскройте вашу мысль более подробно. На данный момент, я не до конца понимаю суть проблемы.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, по большей части я говорю только про тег Google Apps Script. Публика приходит откровенно слабая. Открывают невнятный топик с непонятным содержимым, и на этом процесс пополнения знаниями сообщества заканчивается. То ли жалобы недотягивают до удаления сообщения, то ли есть какие-то другие причины, но оставлять в таком виде жалко. Поэтому и приходится переделывать весь топик, чтобы он имел внятный контекст. А причина, почему так происходит, ясна - пользователь не ценит возможность. Это как в психологии, если не преодолел рубеж, то достижения не имеют ценности.

Comment: @oshliaer Спасибо! Проблема ясна. Как мне кажется, данную проблему никак не поможет решить запрет вопросов, не содержащий пример кода. Скорее это глобальная проблема общения в сети. Согласен, надо думать, как с этим бороться.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, сабж в действии http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/649811 Времени убито много, ачивка не достигнута. Персональнальное удовлетворение минимально.