# Репутация и вопросы, имеющие историческое значение

Tags: поддержка, перевод-блога

<sub>Свободный перевод публикации блога «[Reputation and Historical Archives](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/06/reputation-and-historical-archives/)» от 6 марта 2012 года</sub>

---

Если вы заходили на Мету в последние пару дней, вы наверняка заметили, какая серьёзная дискуссия разгорелась в связи с [недавно изменившимися принципами подсчёта репутации](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes):

> Внесу ясность: **значения репутации остались неизменными, то есть любому действию в системе соответствует прежнее количество баллов репутации**. Но вот что *изменится*:
>
> - Ваша репутация всегда будет соответствовать настоящему положению дел.
> - При удалении сообщений репутация будет меняться гораздо быстрее, и вам не придётся дожидаться перерасчёта (хотя синхронизация значений репутации может занимать до 5 минут после удаления / отмены удаления; чтобы не блокировать цепочку ответов для участника, эта операция ставится в очередь фоновых задач).
> - Перерасчёт больше не нужен.
> - При отмене голоса «за» / «против» восстанавливается исходное количество баллов репутации.
> - При смене голоса «за» / «против» выполняется корректный перерасчёт максимального предела репутации.
> - История изменений репутации на странице участника станет более подробной и точной (например, при удалении сообщения соответствующее изменение отобразится на вкладке репутации на вашей странице).

Всё это, возможно, звучит скучно — и так оно и есть, — но это изменение важно для наших наиболее активных участников, для которых номинальное значение репутации — это наглядный показатель того, как их вклад оценивается сообществом. До настоящего момента значение репутации, отображаемое возле вашего имени на странице учётной записи, лишь приблизительно отражало *реальную* репутацию, [и только перерасчёт](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/) мог устранить все расхождения, накапливавшиеся с течением времени.

К сожалению, вместо внедрения новой функции, что *было бы* воспринято участниками весьма радушно, мы предложили лишь «костыль». Обратите внимание на последний пункт в списке, тот, что про удалённые сообщения. Через определённое время у любого участника сообщества Stack Overflow появляются удалённые сообщения, и они отображаются в истории изменения репутации (особенно у тех, кто присоединился к сообществу на раннем этапе, когда точное понимание *цели* сообщества Stack Overflow ещё только формировалось): вопросы, которые на самом деле не являлись вопросами; ответы в опросах или ветках «Давайте знакомиться», количество которых постоянно росло; то, что казалось разумным и абсолютно нормальным в одно время, а затем было удалено в связи с определением основной тематики сайта, или же информация, которая устарела в связи с изменением технологий. Удаление — важная часть жизненного цикла вопроса в сообществе. [Приведём недавние слова Джеффа](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/):

> Мы знаем, как неприятно закрывать коробку с печеньем. Мы хорошо вас понимаем. Никому из нас не нравится, когда нас лишают чего-то приятного. Но развлекательная составляющая не требует усилий и вызывает привыкание. Без модерации участники сообщества только то и делали бы, что голосовали за простые и весёлые сообщения.

И *ничто* не усиливает неприятные ощущения так, как постоянное напоминание о них, как будто кто-то специально подчёркивает их красной линией каждый раз, когда вы заходите на страницу своей учётной записи:

[image]

Как видно на снимке, здесь даже есть прямая *ссылка* на удалённый ответ — вот так **мы впервые сделали эту информацию доступной!** Реакция последовала незамедлительно: люди стали просматривать историю изменений, изучали все удалённые вопросы и ответы и нашли множество сообщений, которые, [вероятно, не стоило удалять](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432922/significant-new-inventions-in-computing-since-1980), хотя они и *не строго* соответствовали действующим правилам сообщества.

В двух словах, исправление одной ошибки (неточная история изменений репутации) вскрыло несколько других (несовершенство процесса удаления и недостаточно уважительное отношение к внесённому в прошлом вкладу), а также создало новые (обидное отображение баллов репутации по удалённым вопросам).

Поэтому после [длительной дискуссии на Мете](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/124439/community-led-deletionism-a-protocol-for-sanity) о том, как следует поступить в такой ситуации, мы остановились на следующих четырёх исправлениях:

**Первое**: если участник внёс стоящий вклад в сообщество, соответствующая репутация должна сохраняться, даже если добавленное сообщение в конечном счёте будет удалено. Под «стоящим вкладом» мы понимаем следующее:

- Сообщение имеет рейтинг 3 и более.
- Сообщение присутствует на сайте на протяжении как минимум 60 дней.

В быстро меняющихся областях знаний ценная информация рано или поздно устаревает — не стоит бояться добавлять подобную информацию, и за удаление действительно устаревших сведений не должно следовать никакого штрафа. Естественно, желательно обновлять информацию в ответе с помощью правок, но если кто-то другой уже опубликовал хороший ответ с актуальной информацией, у вас должна быть возможность удалить собственное сообщение, сохранив при этом награду за то время, пока ваш ответ *был* полезным.

**Второе**: мы отказались от отображения потерянной из-за удаления вопросов репутации на странице учётной записи участника, если он сам не захочет её увидеть. Помимо этого мы *вообще* не показываем эту информацию всем остальным участникам (за исключением модераторов). Это было грубым нарушением конфиденциальности, и мы сожалеем, что не подумали об этом раньше.

**Третье**: мы решили упростить процедуру удаления и отмены удаления для большинства вопросов в сообществе. Раньше для удаления крайне популярных вопросов требовалось несколько сотен голосов. Несмотря на правильность этой идеи, на практике участники переставали голосовать и просили модераторов удалить сообщение за них. Мы уж точно не стремились создать больше сложностей для модераторов, при этом ограничив демократичность сообщества. Отныне для удаления даже самых популярных вопросов потребуется от 3 до 10 голосов, и аналогичное количество понадобится для их восстановления.

**Последнее, но не менее важное**: мы ищем способы сохранить наиболее полезные [или даже просто интересные](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2697/) вопросы в истории сообщества и сделать их *доступными* в том или ином виде. Внесу ясность: большинство из приведённых примеров содержат вопросы, которые сегодня не стоило бы задавать... Но некоторые из них, честно говоря, гениальны — и потерять их просто потому, что они неидеально соответствуют нашему строгому формату вопросов и ответов, было бы неправильно. Пока что мы добавили блокировку «Историческое значение», которая полностью замораживает вопрос вместе с ответами, предотвращая дальнейшие правки, голосование, ответы или отметки тревогой. При этом вопрос удаляется из общего списка вопросов на сайте, но остаётся доступным и видимым для всех по ссылке. В настоящий момент такая блокировка выполняется полностью вручную и только модераторами: мы посмотрим, что из этого получится, а затем подкорректируем и расширим её со временем.

Comment: "мы отказались от отображения баллов репутации, потерянных по удалённым вопросам, на странице учётной записи для всех участников (за исключением модераторов и тех, кто попросит нас об этом отдельно)". А каким образом надо "просить отдельно"?

Comment: Сколько же там в обсуждениях повылазило reputation whores. Мерзко как-то.

Comment: Я не уверен что применять слово "недавно" по отношению к событиям 2012 года - хорошая идея, даже в переводе.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Видимо, запросом через [механизм обратной связи](/contact).

Comment: @PavelMayorov Это перевод статьи. На мой взгляд, стоит по максимуму придерживаться оригинала. В статье можно было бы заменить много всего, но тогда это уже будет не перевод, а новая статья!

Comment: Добавьте хотя бы примечание переводчика: *"в связи с недавно [в 2012 году - прим. перев.] изменившимися принципами подсчёта репутации"* если считаете что исправлять текст недопустимо.

Comment: @PavelMayorov в самом начале есть ссылка на оригинал. Если вы считаете необходимым добавить какие–либо уточнения или поменять что–либо в переводе, пожалуйста, внесите улучшающую правку.

Comment: Чем ссылка на оригинал принципиально отличается от ссылки на гугл-диск в вопросах на основном сайте? Почему мы считаем вопросы где для понимания нужно перейти по ссылке недопустимыми, а для справочной информации это считается допустимым?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Проще было бы исправить, чем выяснять допустимость ссылок. Я бы и сам исправил, но этот текст с "недавно" часть текста ссылки и [в 2012 году - прим. перев.] там как будет смотреться не очень. Возможно, было бы лучше как-то сноску сделать, но я не умею её делать.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Пожалуйста, давайте отделять «ответы–ссылки» от ссылки на источник: этот текст написан на основе другого источника, о чем явно говорится в самом начале статьи, дается ссылка на источник. Не до конца понимаю ваш пример с ссылкой на гугл–диск на основном сайте.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky этот текст без ссылки на источник меняет смысл и становится дезинформацией; его невозможно прочитать и понять не переходя по ссылке

Comment: @PavelMayorov Мы написать статью, можем перевести. Это совершенно разные подходы. Я допускаю, что переводя публикацию из блога почти 6 летней выдержки, что–то может выглядеть несколько иначе. На мой взгляд, публикация интересна в исходном виде, так как дает возможность понять, почему движок выглядит так, а не иначе. Если бы мы просто описывали работу движка, это был бы не перевод, а faq–вопрос, который был бы написан с нуля со ссылкой на подтверждения (статью в блоге). Подчеркну, это перевод. Если вы видите явные недостатки перевода, пожалуйста, внесите улучшающую правку.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, просить вот так: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H890s.png

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, ну ты загнул про support. И я бы слово "просить" в переводе заменил бы на что-нибудь другое.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, про это знаю. Мне казалось там что–то другое было. Хотя вполне может быть то, о чем говорится, уже давно получило автоматизацию.

Comment: @Qwertiy Пожалуйста, поменяйте так, как вы считаете будет лучше воспринято.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, поменял перевод всего абзаца: _"Second, we won’t display reputation lost to deleted questions on your profile unless you explicitly ask for it, and won’t display it _at all _to other people (apart from moderators). This was an egregious privacy violation, and we sincerely apologize for not catching it sooner."_

Comment: @Qwertiy Большое спасибо!