# Индивидуальные предпочтения сообщества против всеобщей политики SE: что сильнее?

Tags: поддержка

Этот текст — перевод очень важного [ответа](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124915/154101) на вопрос [Individual community preferences vs. SE network policy: who wins?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124911/154101)

---

**До какой степени отдельные сообщества/сайты сети SE могут переопределять правила и нормы сети SE? Каковы границы этих возможностей?***

---

Что ж, сообщества *могут* переопределять нормы и правила в значительной степени, потому что вся система построена на том, что сообщества сами следят за исполнением норм. Более того, они *должны бы* этим заняться: ведь если сообщество не выработает свои правила, *и* не принимает наши, оно останется вовсе без правил. [Как отмечает Роберт, мы даём много рекомендаций](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124913/811), но каждое сообщество должно **пройти этот путь самостоятельно**, и в течение этого процесса, каждый сайт приобретает собственную индивидуальность. Например, некоторые сайты очень жёстко придерживаются строгой формы вопроса и тематики, при этом другие предоставляют куда больше свободы. *И это нормально!..*

### Игнорирование правил

Когда мы строили Stack Exchange, одной из наших основных идей было учиться на опыте тех, кто уже прошёл похожий путь. Мы старались перенимать то, что работало у других, и избегать ошибок, которые мы там замечали. USENET, wikiHow, Experts Exchange и многочисленные  форумы — у них есть чему поучиться. Из всех наших предшественников для меня лично самым большим источником вдохновения (но также и предупреждений о возможных проблемах) является Википедия: в конце-концов, это почтенное сообщество справляется с испытаниями и невзгодами служения огромной и разнообразной массе пользователей уже в течение длительного времени. Среди их неисчислимых норм и правил можно увидеть вот такое [мета-правило](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%98%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0):

> [...] Если какое-либо правило мешает вам улучшать Википедию или поддерживать её функционирование, **игнорируйте его**.

Вот так вредный совет, а? Он как бы превращает все остальные правила в [тест на внимательность](http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?t=24333), верно?

Не-а. Это мета-правило не даёт читателю полной свободы, оно скорее служит напоминанием, что правила придуманы для достижения определённой цели, и что намного лучше концентрироваться на достижении этой цели, чем на выполнении правил. В согласии с утончённой традицией Википедии, существует [разъяснение к этому правилу](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%98%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0#%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82_%C2%AB%D0%98%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%C2%BB?), в котором есть вот какие ключевые моменты:

> - Не надо бездумно следовать письменным инструкциям — обращать внимание следует лишь на то, стала ли энциклопедия лучше после того, как вы сделали ту или иную правку.
> - Сила правила не в том, что оно именуется «правилом» или «руководством», а в том, что оно отражает мнения и методы работы множества участников. [...]
> - Большинство правил являются в конечном счёте *описательными*, а не *предписывающими*; они представляют собой описание практики, существовавшей на момент их составления. Иногда они отстают от реальности. [...]

Мне кажется, эти моменты резюмируют и то, как мы должны понимать нормы Stack Exchange: не как непостижимые разумом указания свыше, а как советы, основанные на опыте: идеи, которые другие сообщества *пробовали*, и увидели, что это работает (или не работает), — и нормы, которые, как мы видим, эти сообщества установили себе в результате экспериментов. Например:

- Хотите сайт со списками рекомендаций? Предупреждаем: из-за них канул в Лету по крайней мере один сайт, и возникли яростные дискуссии на многих других. Если вам нужны эксперты на сайте, лучше сконцентрируйтесь на вопросах, которые требуют определённых знаний для ответа.
- Хотите помочь с покупкой снаряжения? Если это снаряжение быстро меняется, вам скоро придётся расчищать горы устаревших, бесполезных ответов.
- Хотите ответы на очень субъективные вопросы? Требуйте, чтобы ответы подкреплялись фактами и опытом, иначе вы получите просто множество холиваров.
- ...

Сообщество выражает предпочтения своими действиями на сайте: отвечает на какие-то вопросы, а какие-то закрывает, минусует, ставит на них флаги. Дискуссии на Мете нужны для того, чтобы координировать свои действия, и донести сложившийся внутри сообщества консенсус членам сообщества, равно как и всем другим. Таким образом, правило на Stack Exchange обычно принимает вид формулировки проблемы и предлагаемого решения, которое и будет применяется в соответствующих случаях.

Вы можете наплевать на правила, **но у вас не получится игнорировать проблемы, из-за которых правила возникли**. По крайней мере если вашей целью являются хорошие ответы на вопросы с реальными проблемами. И да, это должно таки быть вашей целью!..

### Мы всё ещё не делаем грузовик

Очевидно, какие-то вещи остаются неизменными: мы создаём сайты вопросов и ответов, не дискуссионные форумы и не списки сервисов. Как бы вам не хотелось завести [Ня!.SE](http://www.reddit.com/r/aww/), мы [*просто не делаем грузовики*](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/02/listen-to-your-community-but-dont-let-them-tell-you-what-to-do.html), и мы не дадим вам [забивать микроскопом гвозди](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/10105). Вот почему даже на сайтах, на которых есть свои модераторы, мы иногда вмешиваемся, чтобы напомнить людям, какова цель всех этих сайтов, и постараться направить их на эту цель.

---

Автор перевода благодарит за неоценимую помощь в подготовке перевода участников @FoggyFinder, @Suvitruf (в алфавитном порядке) и неназванных других.

---

*Оригинальный текст приводил ещё пример переопределения допустимой тематики сайтом как один из поводов для вопроса. Я не перевожу «мотивирующую часть» вопроса, поскольку она не так интересна.

Comment: Стоит отменить, что оригинальный вопрос касался прежде всего политики сайтов по отношению к контенту - онтопика, причин закрытия, списков литературы и софта, и прочего, что у нас и сейчас значительно отличается от code golf - именно поэтому в ответе приведены примеры исключительно по правилам для контента. Очевидно, что мы не может переопределить [Privacy Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy), [Cookie Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/cookie-policy), и, возможно, еще некоторые глобальные policy сети.

Comment: @PashaPash: Это утверждение («касался прежде всего контента») нуждается в подтверждении ссылками на конкретный текст. В ответе говорится о произвольных правилах. Очевидно, примеры не могут охватить вообще всё.

Comment: Тем не менее, очевидно что некоторые политики (тот же legal, включая запрет на Hate Speech) и некоторые правила поменять нельзя (например, модель начисления репутации - одинаковая на разных сайтах. хотя пороги привелегий могут быть разными). Прямо в тексте упоминается запрет по крайней мере части не-legal правил - модели QA. Т.е. да, перевод хороший и нужный - но стоит понимать, что часть правил и принципов даже в 2012 (дата оригинального ответа) была зафиксирована для всей сети, а относительно еще некоторой части, которая была введена после 2012-го года, лично у меня есть некоторые сомнения.

Comment: Оригинальный вопрос касался конкретной ситуации шестилетней давности, но таки автор специальным образом выделил вопрос, на который он хочет получить ответ. Здесь присутствует перевод этого вопроса. Что не так, и зачем вам перевод устаревшей конкретики при наличии общего вопроса?

Comment: текст хороший, только было бы лучше,  чтобы явный вопрос в вопросе был, а ответ на него поместить в форму ответа.

Comment: *"...правила придуманы для достижения определённой цели, и что намного лучше концентрироваться на достижении этой цели, чем на выполнении правил"* -- двумя руками ЗА!

Comment: @jfs: Вопрос — две строчки (выделенные жирным в начале), я хотел поместить сверху главное.

Comment: я уверен, что как опытный участник, вы понимаете что я имел в виду, говоря что вопрос в вопросе, а ответ в поле ответа.

Comment: @jfs: Конечно! Я сознательно нарушил строгость формы, чтобы поставить акцент на смысле, ведь двухстрочный вопрос будет провоцировать ответы от участников. Цель моего поста, однако же, есть именно перевод ответа, вопрос по сути играет вторичную роль. Поэтому я поместил наиболее важную часть именно в вопросе. Кстати, именно к этому — следованию не букве, а духу — и призывает переведённый текст.

Comment: @VladD дело не в букве, а в вашем намерении. Если просто проинформировать без обсуждения хотели, то как есть нормально. Если хотели бы, чтобы и другие участники высказались по вопросу, то ответ в ответ можно было бы переместить.

Comment: @jfs: Я следую традиции переводов: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2697/10105. Это не дискуссия, это просто информация к размышлению.